# Building a package leveraging Service Cloud without a hard dependency

Tags: managed-package, package-dependency

We'd like to include some dependencies on Service Cloud into our managed package. The question is: if we do this can we have a hard dependency on Service Cloud? Can we use Service Cloud features somehow without having a hard dependency on it? So our customers who don't have SC will still be able to use other features of the package

I know we can build another package with a dependency on the existing one, but can we build the functionality into the existing one?